# angular not finding resources when deployed inside nginx using Docker

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I am trying my hands on Docker and Nginx to deploy my angular app, however, I am facing a problem.

When I run the command: npm run build, my index.html has the following script references:

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

From what I feel, these are relative paths, and hence when nginx starts, and my index.html is inside firstApp, then on accessing these files the resource URL should be created as:

```
http://localhost/firstApp/runtime.js
```

but when I run the application in browser, I get 404 error, as Nginx is trying to find the resource at:

```
http://localhost/runtime.js
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with jsons. [Complete solution](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/angular-in-docker-with-nginx-supporting-environments-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-bb9f1724e984) how to deploy angular on docker. However I had still problem with serving json. I edit docker image and nginx config like this:

**Docker:**

```
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

COPY --from=node /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/mime.types
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY mime.types /etc/nginx/mime.types
```

**Nginx:**

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
             autoindex  on;
        }
         location ~* \.(json)$ {
        }
    }
}
```

[Mime](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/mime.types)

I'm not master in nginx so maybe there is any better solution.